# Cursor doesn't blink in a ui dialog (Chrome only)

Tags: google-chrome, jquery-ui-dialog, jquery-ui-draggable

Here is a piece of code that shows an issue I'm having http://jsfiddle.net/XmqgA/

HTML:

```
 <div id="dialogg" style="display:none">
   <input type="text" id="textinp" />
 </div>

 <p>Draggable boxes. Click a clickable box to open a dialog</p>
 <div class="draggable ui-sortable">
   <div class="dragme" id="clickbox">Clickable box</div>
   <div class="dragme">Box</div>
 </div>

 <br/>

 <p>Simple button that opens up a dialog</p>
 <button id="click">Click</button>
```

JS:

```
$('.draggable').sortable({
    connectWith: ".draggable",
    items: "> .dragme",
    appendTo: "body"
});

$("#click").unbind().bind("click", function () {
    $("#dialogg").dialog();
    $("#textinp").focus();
});
$("#clickbox").unbind().bind("click", function () {
    $("#dialogg").dialog();
    $("#textinp").focus();
});
```

Basically I have a simple button, a draggable/sortable element and a ui-dialog window with a text input field.

Both button and a sort element have an on-click event that opens up a ui-dialog.
Everything works fine except for the fact that when you open a dialog by clicking on the sort element a cursor/caret inside an input box in the ui-dialog won't blink. However in both cases input field will have focus.

Seems like this can be only replicated in Chrome but I couldn't find it among Chrome-only bugs.

Thanks!

Comment: Does anybody have any ideas on how I can fix that?